# wget redirect http://example.comhttp/example.com/

Tags: proxy, wget

I'm getting a wrong redirect with `wget`:

```
http://example.comhttp/example.com/
```

and he tries to download http://example.comhttp/example.com/index.html
instead of http://example.com/index.html

I'm doing websites maps by wget (for many domains, not just one) with following command:

```
wget --spider --recursive --level=2 --no-verbose --follow-tags=a --wait=0.5 "http://example.com" -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=http://user:pass@1.2.3.4:3128
```

for 100 domains 90% are ok, but at least 10% get such an error, like described on beginning.

**IMPORTANT: this error is only when I use proxy, is it wget bug?**

EDIT: I have found out that it is because of **3proxy** software used to set up proxy, now question is why this is happening? Example urls:

```
http://leylandslearningcentre.com.au
http://www.roundhillagri.co.nz/
http://barkersphotos.co.nz
```

Comment: Well, without a space in between, what did you expect? `http://example.comhttp/example.com/` looks like a single URL and if that is what is passed to Wget, the outcome seems valid.

Comment: But I use good url in command: `http://example.com`, then wget somehow see redirect to `http://example.comhttp/example.com/` and try to fetch it.

Comment: Share the entire output you see

Comment: I don't have now url list of websites which cause it, but it was something like:
`http://example.com/ found redirect 301 following

http://example.comhttp/example.com/ error index.html not found`

Comment: Seems like a bad response from the server. Unless you can provide more accurate logs, this is the best I can do.

Comment: I have edited question, it is related with 3proxy.

Comment: I have changed 3proxy to tinyproxy and it works like it should be, no errors, problem solved.